# SQL (Redshift) error when using case when - this type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to return a couple of 'average if' columns using the following:

```
select 
    date,
    avg(case when hour >= 23 or hour <= 6) then (select price) else null end) as price1,
    avg(case when (hour >= 16 and hour <= 18) then (select price) else null end) as price2
from 
    xxxxxxxxx
where 
    date <= '2019-12-31' and
    date >= '2018-12-01'
group by 
    date
order by  
    date
```

it works when I use each avg(case when) individually but when I use them both I get the error

> Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Are you sure your parentheses on line 2  are correct?

Comment: just replace `(select price)` with `price`

Answer (score 1):

Why the `select` in the `select`?

```
select date,
       avg(case when hour >= 23 or hour <= 6 then price end) as price1,
       avg(case when hour >= 16 and hour <= 18 then price end) as price2
from xxxxxxxxx
where date <= '2019-12-31' and
      date >= '2018-12-01'
group by date
order by date;
```

The `else null` is also redundant.